# Should I go with Django admin or write my own one?

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm doing some projects with Django and I do not use the Django admin, instead I've created some simple admin application by myself. But of course I still thinking if this is the good way to go.

Why I did the choice to go on my own admin is juts then I have full flexibility and I can do whatever I want. Also I can have really unique interface. While the standard Django admin saves some time when you starting the project. But then if I want to have really good flexibility I need to start modify it... Also about the interface, I know that it allowsto overwrite some templates, but I want to change everything (including all the layout, images, css and so on).

If those reasons are quite reasonable to go for your own admin? Especially if I don't need very fancy things to admin my page?

Thanks!

Comment: You can always use the django admin alongside your custom admin. I have specialized admins doing model updates/deletes in ways the admin cant - I still use the admin for default viewing.

Also, the cost of building an admin page is so low, why don't you go write your admin app and decide to roll your own later?

Comment: Thanks for comment. While I already started to adopt my modules to my admin, so probably I will just go with my custom one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i've faced the same situation once before . and here is what i believe is correct:

1. in case you are building a big project : where you need to have a full customization, and lot of fixes in the future .. **write your own admin**. in fact. you should always do that - i mean writing your own thing -. not just with django.
2. in case your are building a small project : where you want to have just a couple of features and build them fast. ( have fast results ) . it'll be a bad idea writing a new one, since it wastes time.

however , if you are doing this on your own ( no boss waiting for you to finish ) i suggest that you write your own admin . it's a good experience, and will help you in the future.

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, I think I will go with my own admin while it helps to learn new things and will not limit me... Of course for the small project I bet it is better just to start with default admin, but while I plan to use this system for lot of projects - I fell that then my own will be good. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The Django Admin lets you overwrite all templates. It is also very flexible as it lets you subclass a lot of its inner workins.

And as Yuji says; you can always write your own views where needed.

I would definitely go with Django Admin.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the django amin and modify it as you wish, [here's how](http://python.mirocommunity.org/video/1715/customizing-the-django-admin)